# How to empty edittext without setText("");

Tags: android

Is there a way to reset the edittext value without setting text like:

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.yoursXmlId)).setText("");
```

**EDIT:**

Textchanged listner is called when i use setText("").

Comment: if u want programmatically then u have to use this method i think.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Another option is: [`EditText.getText().clear();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#clear%28%29) But you'll have to cast anyway:

`((EditText) findViewById(R.id.yoursXmlId)).getText().clear();`

Comment: good one but if he will use like this then he can also use setText("") also i think

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I thought this answer would clear my bug. Still its the answer i was expecting :)

Comment: This works, but if you try to write something in the `EditText` again the initial text appears again

Comment: if anyone is getting the issue please use 
editText.post(() -> editText.getText().clear());

Answer (score 20):

you can use following way

**Kotlin:**

```
myEditText.text.clear()
```

**Java:**

```
EditText myEditText = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.yoursXmlId));
myEditText.getText().clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

A function for that would be:

```
fun setTextViewEmpty(textView: TextView){
(textView as EditText ).text.clear()   }
```

inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17967496/8940448)

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where a Samsung device was not blanking out text with setText(""), so I used:

String BLANK = "\u0020"; // space character

setText (BLANK);

and it worked this way. It may have been a font issue.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is finding the selected answer not working
please try with

```
editText.post(() -> editText.getText().clear());
```

or

```
editText.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                editText.getText().clear();
            }
        });
```