# stop refreshing my keyboard when using EditText.setText(value)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

below is my edittext with rxandroid. and the problem is my keyboard refresh when i remove certain characters '\\' and setText in searchbox. So it makes my keyboard switch back to alphabets (picture 1) and while I want to remain on numbers and special characters (picture 2). Is there any way to set EditText text without refreshing the page?

```
 SearchEditText = RxTextView.textChanges(searchbox)
                .map(CharSequence::toString)
                .debounce(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                //.observeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // can test without this
                //.switchMap(RegrexAndActualNumberHelper::TrySearchValidation) // can test without this
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(result -> {
                //    searchbox.setText(result); // settext make the page refresh and reset the keyboard to alphabets
                    searchbox.setSelection(searchbox.getText().length()); // move the cursor b to end of the line.
                    if( !result.isEmpty() ){
                        getInventoryItems(view, searchbox, recycler);
                    }
                });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I figure out quick fix for this behavior. Instead of using setText, I use "searchbox.getText().clear();" and "searchbox.append(result);" and voila, it works, the screen never get refreshed and keyboard stay at where it is.

Comment: I get the idea from this stackoverflow question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967404/how-to-empty-edittext-without-settext